# Get total of a data row asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datatable, dataset

Im trying to get the values from each column in a single row to equal a total. Here is the code that im using to achieve this in c# asp.net

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables.Add("InspireTable");
        string pass = (String)Session["name"];
        if (pass.Equals("High"))
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Inspire", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("SNS", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("TT", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Music", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(string));


            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Inspire"] = "Score";
            row["SNS"] = 10;
            row["TT"] = 10;
            row["Music"] = 0;

            dt.Rows.Add(row);
            Chart1.DataSource = dt;
            this.GridView1.Visible = true;
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
```

Any ideas? I have tried calling each column and adding them but that seem not to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the old [`DataTable.Compute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) method, for example:

```
int snsTotal = (int) dt.Compute("SUM(SNS)", null); // the second argument is the filter
```

Here's the "modern" [**Linq**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx) approach:

```
int snsTotal = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(r => r.Field<int>("SNS"));
```

**Edit**: it seems as if you want to sum the numeric values of each row into a "total"-column. Then you can use a Column-Expression:

```
dt.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(int), "SNS + TT + Music");
```