# If Statements in DataTables asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I am using a `DataTable` which has a total column within it which adds all the the columns up to give a final value. But I need to make it so if the total is over a limit it will give a message like "You have gone over what you are allowed".
so it would look something like this

```
if(dt.Column("Total") > 30)
{
   //Display message in label
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "adds all the columns up".

Comment: Is this the same question as [**your last**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13647103/284240)?

Comment: No that was to get the total now i just need to say that when the total equals a 30 or what ever then display in a label"Over the limit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "old" [`DataTable.Compute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) method with a columns expression, for example:

```
int total = (int) dt.Compute("SUM(Total)", null); // the second argument is the filter
if(total > 30)
{
     LblMessage.Text = "Total value exceeded maximum of 30!";
}
```

Here's the "modern" [**Linq**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx) approach:

```
int total = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Total"));
// ...
```